# Azure DevOps OnPrem - Service Connection failed - Failed to obtain the Json Web Token

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019, serviceconnection

So, a bit of a strange one and I'm hoping that someone's had this issue and found a fix (Or understands why it's happening)

So this used to work without any issue... Just started happening this week - to our knowledge

Basically, when you create a new Azure Resource Manager **Service Connection** within Azure DevOps you get the following error;
`Failed to obtain the Json Web Token(JWT) using service principal client ID. Exception Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

This only happens on our On-Prem Azure DevOps server - I can create the service connection with the same settings on our Dev.Azure.com version without any issues.

**Troubleshooting**

- Created multiple Service Principals
- Tried different subscriptions
- Tried giving SP Owner permissions to the subscription
- Even if you try to re-verifying an existing service connection you get the same error
- Works in Dev.Azure.com
- Been no networking changes regarding our on-prem stuff
- Still able to action releases using the existing service connections (Even though you can't verify them)
- Tried creating another secret as advised my the MS troubleshooting page
- I have a PS script to gain the bearer token using the SP that I created and that works

Obviously, I've tried googling this issue, it comes up in a couple of places but none of which have a resolution or an understanding of why it's happening...

TIA

Answer (score 5):

The solution can be found on the Troubleshooting page accessible from the "Troubleshoot" link in the Edit pane of the Service Connection: [Troubleshoot ARM service connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-rm-endpoint?view=azure-devops#failed-to-obtain-the-jwt-by-using-the-service-principal-client-id)

Relevant section pasted here for reference/persistence:

> **Failed to obtain the JWT by using the service principal client ID**
>
> This issue occurs when you try to verify a service connection that has an expired secret.
>
> To resolve this issue:
>
> 1. Go to **Project settings** > **Service connections**, and then select the service connection you want to modify.
> 2. Select **Edit** in the upper-right corner, and then make any change to your service connection. The easiest and recommended change is to add a description.
> 3. Select **Save** to save the service connection.
>
> > ⚠ Note
> >
> > Select **Save**. Don't try to verify the service connection at this step.
>
> 4. Exit the service connection edit window, and then refresh the service connections page.
> 5. Select **Edit** in the upper-right corner, and now select **Verify**.
> 6. Select **Save** to save your service connection.

Answer (score 0):

The following link is for a different variation of your problem, but the first comment suggests a Powershell script that could be run that might provide more details?

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7537132d-a363-4868-86fa-c008de180ff1/failed-to-obtain-the-json-web-tokenjwt-for-service-principal?forum=TFService

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I've tried that and I'm allowed to log in as a SP. Really doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Silly question, since you mention this just started happening to you. Have you logged out of Azure DevOps, logged out of the Azure Portal, closed your browsers, and then re-launched and tried again? I'm wondering if the problem is with the bearer token in your own session.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure DevOps OnPrem - Service Connection failed - Failed to obtain the Json Web Token

According to the official document [Troubleshoot Azure Resource Manager service connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-rm-endpoint?view=azure-devops-2019#failed-to-obtain-an-access-token-or-a-valid-refresh-token-was-not-found).

> These errors typically occur when your session has expired. You can
> refer to this document and follow the steps:
>
> 1. Sign out of Azure Pipelines or TFS.
> 2. Open an InPrivate or incognito browser window and navigate to
>    https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/team-services/.
> 3. If you are prompted to sign out, do so.
> 4. Sign in using the appropriate credentials.
> 5. Choose the organization you want to use from the list.
> 6. Select the project you want to add the service connection to.
> 7. Create the service connection you need by opening the Settings page.
>    Then, select `Services` > `New service connection` > `Azure Resource Manager`.

And you could try to run below script on the Azure DevOps OnPrem machine and can verify if able to generate the access token.

[GetAccessToken.ps1](https://github.com/Ajay-MS/UtilityScripts/blob/master/Subscription/GetAccessToken.ps1)